# Why can't I access to the files of ec2 instance from its RStudio Server?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, rstudio-server

I am able to `ssh` to the ec2 instance I created. I also set up the RStudio Server and log in on the 8787 port. However, in the RStudio server, I cannot the see files on the ec2 instance. For example, I have a data (scp'd from my local) in the ~/data/inputData.rda, but this data is not shown in the file pane of RStudio Server, instead only "R" folder is on the RStudio. Even if I create a rscript from RStudio Server, I cannot see the script on the instance.

Key codes I used to setup RStudio Server:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install R4
sudo yum install rstudio-serve-rhel-1.3.1093-x86_64.rpm
sudo useradd rstudio
sudo passwd rstudio
```

I believe I need to set up something to make ec2 instance and RStudio Server connected. Can anyone help me guide through this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out and it's simple. The rstudio server files are stored in /home/rstudio

```
sudo su 
cp <your file> /home/rstudio
```